# How to redirect delayed from within a widget that is built twice

Tags: flutter

On my app's splash screen, I am setting the status bar color using `SystemChrome` and issue a delayed redirect to the main screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      title: 'App',
      routes: {'/': (context) => First(),
      '/2': (context) => Second()},
    );
  }
}

class First extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> _navigateToFollowUpRoute(BuildContext context) async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/2'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
      statusBarColor: Colors.black,
    ));
    print('building first');
    _navigateToFollowUpRoute(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("go")),
    );
  }
}


class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("second")),);
  }
}
```

Calling `setSystemUIOverlayStyle()` seems to cause a widget rebuild, which triggers the delay twice, which causes the redirect to be called twice. Of course, this causes an exception regarding violation of context access (even without this, it would unnecessarily build the `Second` widget twice.

Is there a non-hacky way (thinking about a stateful widget here, "remembering" the initially issued redirect and suppressing the second) to resolve this?

**NOTE:** I need the redirect to happen from within a function in order to dynamically assign the secondary route (only hard-coded in the example for simplicity).

Comment: Using the SystemChrome API from within a `createElement()` override does not cause this problem. However, I'm suspicious of this solution due to the doc stating "It is uncommon for subclasses to override this method."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I need to do something once when the widget is first created, I generally would make it into a Stateful widget and do the one-time call from the `initState` method.

Something else that might be useful is the AnnotatedRegion way of setting the system overlay:

```
new AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
    statusBarColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  child: ....,
);
```